# Autosegmental spreading above and below

Tags: diagrams, linguistics, pst-asr

I'm looking to recreate the two autosegmental diagrams below using the [`pst-asr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-asr?lang=en) package but I can't see a way to do it in the package documentation (I hope this is not due to inattentive reading).

[image]
[image]

I'm able to get half-way there with the code below:

```
\asr[reptype=nots,xgap=1em,syB=-2em,phB=0em]
pIrlEntE-lI{}{$\rightarrow$}{}{}{}{[pɯrɫɑntɑ-ɫɯ]}{}{}{}{}{}{}{`diamond-\textsc{adj}'}|
    \@(1,sy){[$+$B]}
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](4,ph)
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](7,ph)
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](10,ph)
\endasr
```

And loading the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use existing tiers it makes more sense to define new tiers relative to the `ph` tier (which I've set to be at 0 in the `pst-asr` grid).  I've created a `top` and `bot` tier for the features above and below the phoneme line.  Since you didn't provide a minimal document in your question, I've created one which needs to be compiled using `xelatex`. You may need to adapt it to your actual use case.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newtier{top,bot}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts,
 ph=0,ts=0,top=(ph) 5 1em 1em,bot=(ph) -6 1em 1em,botB=-5.5,topB=6,phht=2.5ex}

\begin{document}
\asr[reptype=nots]
pIrlEntE-lI{}{$\rightarrow$}{}{}{}{[pɯrɫɑntɑ-ɫɯ]}{}{}{}{}{}{}{`diamond-\textsc{adj}'}|
    \@(1,bot){[$+$B]}
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](4,ph)
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](7,ph)
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](10,ph)
    \@(1,top){[$-$R]}
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](4,ph)
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](7,ph)
    \-(1,ph)\-[linestyle=dashed](10,ph)
\endasr
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm also using XeLaTeX. Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Miztli Great. For future questions, it's best to supply a minimal document (like the one I posted) with your question which is compilable and contains only the packages and code needed to show the problem. This lets people see exactly what you're doing and also makes it much easier for us to help you.